# Using expect and xmacro to simulate a screen touch beep

Tags: linux, expect

I need to create a beep sound whenever the user touches the screen, the o/s is arch linux and I am using expect and xmacro to achieve this.

The following script is called from .xinitrc and it works when I touch the screen, however it also makes a beep at an exact 10 second interval and I have no idea why or how to stop it.

Any suggestions or ideas why this may be happening ?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn xmacrorec2 -k 27

while { 1 } {
    expect "ButtonPress 1"
    system beep -f 3000 -l 10 &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stmbled upon the solution, it appears that expect is timing out after 10 seconds, so need to prevent this with set timeout -1:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn xmacrorec2 -k 27
set timeout -1
while { 1 } {
    expect "ButtonPress 1"
    system beep -f 3000 -l 50 &
}
```